# How to truncate CampaignInfluence

Tags: sobject, workbench, campaign-influence

`CampaignInfluence` is consuming a large amount of storage as you can see. Now I've tried to access the object through Workbench etc but no luck. Anyone managed to access the object and do some cleaning ...?

[image]